# How to enable change password in OBIEE10g

Tags: oracle, obiee

OBIEE10g Analytics users can not change password by himself. Is there any way to enable user to change his password without the help of BI administrator.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the workaround to enable change password option in BI answers

Step 1: Go to the following location

```
$OracleBI_HOME/web/msgdb/messages
```

Step 2: Open the `controlmessages.xml` file in edit mode and make the following changes

Before:

```
<!-- <HTML><a insert="1"><sawm:messageRef name="kmsgUIChangePassword"/></a></HTML> -->
</WebMessage>
```

After:

```
<WebMessage name="kmsgChangePasswordLink">
<HTML><a insert="1"><sawm:messageRef name="kmsgUIChangePassword"/></a></HTML> 
</WebMessage>
```

Step 3: Re-start the Oracle BI Server and Oracle BI Presentation Server.

Then, you will find the `change password` option under the my account link.